# "Cannot find file or directory" when using Visual Studio in the WSL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a solution in visual studio for C++ in a directory located in the Windows-subsystem for Linux. The exact file is located in 
`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\{username}\some\file\visual\studio`

When I try to run my code I am getting the error: `Cannot open source file: 'main.cpp': No such file or directory`

I can view all of the C++ code in Visual Studio, and it is located in the original spot, i.e. i have not moved the files around after I added them to VS.

I suspect it is a problem with permissions, in order to access the CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1 folder, my PC asks for permissions to access the folder. Could visual studio be prevented from accessing the files due to permissions? could i run VS in some sort of sudo mode?